# intent_filter: run apk build in UNITY from url

Tags: url, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have a problem running the app via url.
I added to manifest intent-filter, but it does not work.
I would like to have the application launch after the url, of course it is on the device.

This is the code activity in my android manifest:

```xml
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="testurl" android:host="app.open"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
```

Is there anyone able to help me?

Comment: url in browser = testurl://app.open

Comment: I'm pretty sure the website (ie app.open in this case) has to also provide a file or DNS record authorizing the app as official.  Have you provided that?/Do you own the website that you are trying to link the app to?

Answer (score 1):

It works. It was necessary to create an html with a URL.